# Report showing 'The definition of the report is invalid' in SSDT 2015

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I have a **SSRS 2008** project with some reports, and recently we update the version, now I open the project with the **SQL Server Data Tools 2015**, and all is fine, I can deploy, edit, update all fine.

The problem comes when I want to create a new report, when I add a DataSet to the report, the preview tab says:

> An error occurred during local report processing
>
> The definition of the report 'Report Name' is invalid

and nothing more happens, I can't preview the report anymore.

Does anyone know if it is a issue of *upgrade/open* a SSRS 2008 solution with SSDT 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research... I couldn't find anything.

So I tried to create the report in **Reporting Services 2008**, and when trying to preview the report after adding a DataSet it show me the same error:

> An error occurred during local report processing
>
> The definition of the report 'Report Name' is invalid

But now, it has an aditional line:

> The shared dataset definition is not valid. details the required
>   attribute 'name' is missing

And after enter the first search result in Google, it looks like **the problem was that my DataSet was a Shared DataSet**, **JoannaK found the same problem** and **also found a workaround**:

> Found a workaround for now: Create the data set as embedded> Convert
>   to Shared Data set Looks like the Name property is set when you start
>   with embedded. report runs and can data sets can be uploaded to the
>   report server

This solves my problem. Hope it helps someone in the future.

Source: [JoannaK from SQL Server Data Tools Preview update for April 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/15/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-april-2016/)

Answer (score 2):

*SSDT is generating a broken dataset definition. To fix it:*

1. Open up the shared dataset's `.rsd` file in a text editor.
2. In the xml therein find the `<DataSet>` opening tag.
3. Add the attribute `Name` (case-sensitive) to that tag, e.g: `<DataSet Name="SomeDataSet">`

Probably should set the `Name` to be the same as the `filename` but doesn't seem to make any difference as far as I can see.

---

*Thanks to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38753141/10245) as without that I never would have got it to work at all.*

VS2015 / SSRS2012

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar error. It mostly occurs as of change in 'SHARED DATASET'.

1. Check for query fields in 'Shared Database Properties', if no fields are there , simply add fields you have included in your query.
2. Check for database connection
3. Check for 'Stored Procedure' and it's result if you have used stored procedure.
4. One can delete old dataset and re-create with same name.
5. As a last option, one can create 'New Dataset' (another one) and bind the new one with the report(take care to map all fields again once you choose to create new dataset.